# Golang proxy in front of k8s api server hangs on kubectl delete pod with 'WINDOW_UPDATE'

Tags: go, kubernetes, proxy, amazon-eks, kubernetes-apiserver

I am writing a Golang based L7 proxy that sits in front of k8s api server. Something like this,

kubectl <----> gateway/proxy <----> AWS EKS API server

[image]

Common `kubectl` commands like `get pods`, `exec`, `run`, `apply`, `create` etc work fine. However, for `kubectl delete pod <name>`, `kubectl` get stuck/hangs.

Generally, these are cases, where `kubectl` adds `watch=true` flag. In this scenario, k8s server does not send `END_STREAM` so my proxy gets stuck in 'read frame WINDOW_UPDATE'

Has anyone seen this? I was looking at `client-go` or `kubernetes` repoa to see how does `kubectl` handle response when `watch=true` is set. Would appreciate any pointers.

Below are my debug logs --

```
2019/10/11 00:50:19 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":authority" = "myproxy.dev.net:8443"
2019/10/11 00:50:19 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":method" = "GET"
2019/10/11 00:50:19 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":path" = "/api/v1/namespaces/guestbook/pods?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dshell-test&resourceVersion=1313006&watch=true"
2019/10/11 00:50:19 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":scheme" = "https"
2019/10/11 00:50:19 http2: decoded hpack field header field "accept" = "application/json"
2019/10/11 00:50:19 http2: decoded hpack field header field "user-agent" = "kubectl/v1.15.2 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/f627830"
2019/10/11 00:50:19 http2: decoded hpack field header field "authorization" = "Bearer LS<REDACTED>
2019/10/11 00:50:19 http2: decoded hpack field header field "accept-encoding" = "gzip"
2019/10/11 00:50:19 http2: server read frame HEADERS flags=END_STREAM|END_HEADERS stream=5 len=86
2019/10/11 00:50:51 http2: server encoding header ":status" = "200"
2019/10/11 00:50:51 http2: server encoding header "audit-id" = "aaa-9682-d7b95a6daa0e"
2019/10/11 00:50:51 http2: server encoding header "content-type" = "application/json"
2019/10/11 00:50:51 http2: server encoding header "date" = "Fri, 11 Oct 2019 00:50:19 GMT"
2019/10/11 00:50:51 http2: Framer 0xc0004beee0: wrote HEADERS flags=END_HEADERS stream=5 len=32
2019/10/11 00:50:51 http2: Framer 0xc0004beee0: wrote DATA stream=5 len=4096 data="{\"type\":\"MODIFIED\",\"object\":{\"kind\":\"Pod\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"metadata\":{\"name\":\"shell-test\",\"namespace\":\"guestbook\",\"selfLink\":\"/api/v1/namespaces/guestbook/pods/shell-test\",\"uid\":\"d2baa702-ebc0-11e9-06652f016772\",\"resourceVersion\":\"1313054\",\"creation" (3840 bytes omitted)
2019/10/11 00:50:51 http2: Framer 0xc0004beee0: wrote DATA stream=5 len=4096 data="0}],\"priority\":0,\"enableServiceLinks\":true},\"status\":{\"phase\":\"Running\",\"conditions\":[{\"type\":\"Initialized\",\"status\":\"True\",\"lastProbeTime\":null,\"lastTransitionTime\":\"2019-10-11T00:48:21Z\"},{\"type\":\"Ready\",\"status\":\"False\",\"lastProbeTime\":null,\"lastTransit" (3840 bytes omitted)
2019/10/11 00:50:51 http2: Framer 0xc0004beee0: read WINDOW_UPDATE stream=5 len=4 incr=6291
2019/10/11 00:50:51 http2: server read frame WINDOW_UPDATE stream=5 len=4 incr=6291
```

Proxy code is written in Golang using `NewSingleHostReverseProxy` and it terminates TLS, patches new connection to k8s api server.

Comment: I suggesting having a look at the gRPC protocol on how this is handled there.

Comment: Please take a look for [Efficient detection of changes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#efficient-detection-of-changes) `Clusters using etcd3 preserve changes in the last 5 minutes by default. When the requested watch operations fail because the historical version of that resource is not available, clients must handle the case by recognizing the status code 410 Gone`